# Launch a UWP application form toast button click in windows action center

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, toast

I want to understand how can I launch an application from toast button click ?.

As per my understanding I am doing below steps:

I have created an UWP app and defined the protocol in package.manifest.   and passing them same in Launch of toast content and my app is installed in the windows.

```
 ToastContent toastContent = new ToastContent()
                {                
                    Launch =  "launchMyApp:",
                    ActivationType = ToastActivationType.Protocol,   
                    Actions= new CustomActions()
                    {
                         new ToastButton("Like","LikeButton")
                        {
                         ActivationType = ToastActivationType.Protocol,                
                         }
                    }
                  };

            }
```

as per my understanding it should launch the application on click on like button. But somehow It is not launching. Could anybody help in finding what I am doing wrong.!!!

Comment: You're toast button is declaring the protocol to use, but not what to do. That's like typing `https://` into your browser and expecting google to show up upon pressing enter

Answer (score 0):

`Launch` defines a callback that clicks on the toast notification itself. If you want to open other applications when you click the button, writing `URI Protocal` in `Launch` will not work.

Try this:

```cs
new ToastButton("Like","launchMyApp:")
{
    ActivationType = ToastActivationType.Protocol,
}
```

Comment: Richard, can you please provide a more concrete example. How the callback should be defined?